# Is there a Datatype in C# for List of comma separated pairs

Tags: c#

Is there a datatype in C# for List of comma separated pairs like below?

```
[(WAN.XX.1.0, WAN.XX.1.1), (WAN.XX.1.2, WAN.XX.1.3), (WAN.XX.1.4, WAN.XX.1.5), (WAN.XX.1.6, WAN.XX.1.7), (WAN.XX.1.8, WAN.XX.1.9)]
```

Comment: Writing a class with two properties is not very complicated and the data looks not very common, so do not expect there is a special datatype

Comment: BTW "comma separated" is representation of data and you can write code to parse or produce that ... but it has nothing to do with a datatype itself

Comment: Is `WAN.XX.1.0` string? Do you want list of comma separated pairs of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` or `List<Tuple<string, string>>` do what you need?.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx .